# Is it possible with CSS to target a h1 but only if it's the very first item in a parent?

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<article id="whatever">
    <h1>First Title</h1>
    <p>Test</p>
    <h1>Second Title</h1>
    <p>Test</p>
</article>
```

I'd like to add some top margin to the first h1 but only if the first element inside article is the h1.

I can't use `:first-of-type`, `:first-child`, etc because the markup in the article is dynamic, so if I used `article > h1:first-of-type` this would allow the margin top for this particular content, but if the content was:

```
<article id="whatever">
    <p>First Title</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <h1>Second Title</h1>
    <p>Test</p>
</article>
```

The second title would get the margin-top which I don't want. I need to target the h1 if it is the very first element in the article only.

Comment: `article > h1:first-child` should do it

Comment: How? first-child would still apply to the h1 in the second code example right?

Comment: no it won't, try and see

Comment: I'm confused as to why you think you can't use `:first-child`, since "the very first element in the parent element" is its description.

Comment: `:first-child` can only ever match elements that are what the pseudo class says: The first child element in their parent. `h1:fist-child` only further narrows down which elements this matches. It targets any element that is both: an `h1`, and `:first-child` of its parent.

Comment: Of course i can use :first-child - sorry I got tunnel vision here, I've been inside too long.